# Multiple attribute selectors in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I have some SCSS code for setting some positioning elements, it's pretty simple;

```
[no-padding*="left"] { padding-left: 0 !important; }
[no-padding*="right"] { padding-right: 0 !important; }
[no-padding*="bottom"] { padding-bottom: 0 !important; }
[no-padding*="top"] { padding-top: 0 !important; }
```

But I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to write this using the `[attr*=value]` selector, for example...

```
[no-padding] {
    &[*="left"] { ... }
    &[*="right"] { ... }
}
```

Putting that code, I get the following error ...

> Invalid CSS after "...="left"] { ... ": expected "{", was "}")

Comment: As an aside, I note it's bad-form to have presentational markup as it strongly-couples your markup with its appearance. Are you sure there isn't a more abstract way of achieving the same effect?

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how it is any different than using class selectors. Isn't that essentially the same amount of coupling?

Comment: Please note, I'm not saying I think you're wrong. I just don't understand. What is different about `<div no-padding="left">` and `<div class="no-padding-left">` as far as coupling goes?

Comment: I mean, aren't all of the major CSS frameworks doing this now? Bootstrap and Angular Materials are filled with declarative attribute selectors. Though what you're saying does make a bit of sense now that I think harder on it, I've always felt CSS was a clunky way to style things that had a lot of coupling.

Comment: `{ ... }` is not a valid declaration block. That's why you're getting that error message. That error message isn't actually relevant, though.

Comment: No, SCSS does not support that syntax. The "cleaner way" is to not use attributes like this (which wouldn't validate anyway unless it was `data-no-padding') and use classes.

Comment: The `{ ... }` doesn't actually look like that. It's just to symbolize that I have code there.

Comment: @Dai I'm still not completely certain why you say this is a bad idea, but I'll do some researching to try and understand. To directly answer your question ... "No". I'm not sure there isn't a more abstract way of achieving the same effect.

Comment: Basically put, there's a lot of situations I keep running into where an element needs just 1 or 2 properties - usually something stupid like a `float`, a `margin` set, a `padding` set. Sometimes, I cannot use the `style` attribute because `angular` or some other plugin interacts with it for some reason at times, so I was trying to find alternative ways of adding those properties without creating a long slew of unique classes.

Comment: This seemed like a fairly natural way to do it, to me. But of course that doesn't make it the right way, or even a good way.

Comment: Just curious, how is "angular or some other plugin" affecting the ability to use classes to style elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `@each` loop would be another way to write this:

```
$directions: left right bottom top;
@each $i in $directions {
  [no-padding*="#{$i}"] {
    padding-#{$i}: 0 !important;
  }
}
```